# How to use numpy in google appengine standard python2 with WSGIApplication?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I want to use library numpy in my webapp2.WSGIApplication. I use Python2, App Engine Standard. 
I haved added numpy to app.yaml with:

```
libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: 1.6.1
```

And installed numpy to my local environnement with :

```
pip install --user numpy==1.6.1
```

But when I do 
`import numpy`, I have error "No module named numpy". Do you have some suggestions about my error ?
But `import numpy` works for my endpoints.

In my main.py, I have:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import webapp2
from src.app.book.handlers import BookHandler

ndb.toplevel(webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/app/book', BookHandler)]))
```

In BookHandler of handlers.py, I have

```
import numpy 
numpy.trapz([1, 2, 3], dx=10)
```

I have "No module named numpy" error when I run /app/book

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I have added some infos in the question, I am not sure if you can find informations you need

Comment: Do you get this error when running the application locally, or when deploying? I have tried installing `numpy 1.6.1` in my local environment to no avail, but worked fine when deploying. I could made it work on my side by running `pip install numpy`, wuth no version specified.

Comment: @JoanGrau I have run locally, I have not tested when deploying. I have installed 
`pip install --user numpy==1.6.1` without problem, but I have the error.

Comment: I can only think that the `--user` flag is messing up the installation in the python environment. Can you try to recreate the environment, without using the `virtualenv` flag `--system-site-packages`, and then install the packages without the `--user` flag?

Comment: @JoanGrau Thanks for your advice. In fact, I didn't use virtualenv, I install directly in my environment. If I do `pip install numpy` without --user, I have error `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.16.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.` If I do `sudo pip install numpy`, I have error `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: Try to first create a python virtual environment, use the command `virtualenv env` followed by `source env/bin/activate`, and install all the packages you need for your application, without using any flags in the `pip` command.